# Multiple methods named error. Multiple classes involved

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, 64-bit

The last line of the code "return [cell height]" is giving me an error "Multiple methods named "height" found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes". This code runs fine on 32 bit but not on 64 bit(simulators).

Please can someone help solve this one. There are other posts which mention this but they have just one type of class that can be type casted. I have different classes in the array self.cells

I can check for each "cell" for its class type and then return the respective height but that is a cumbersome code. Is there a better way of doing this?

Help much appreciated.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id cell = self.cells[indexPath.row];
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[TripCell class]])
    {
        return 150;
    }
    return [cell height];
}
```

Comment: try returning cell.bounds.size.height .... [cell height] isn't a method you can call unless you made it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "cell" is declared as having type "id". That means the compiler has not the slightest idea what kind of object it is. So if you send the message "height" to an object declared as id, the compiler assumes it is one of the methods named "height" that it knows about. If you have different methods named "height" with different return types, then the compiler doesn't know what this call will return.

For example, if you have one method - (int) height in one class, and another method - (CGFloat) height in another class, the compiler doesn't know whether the value returned by the method is int or CGFloat.

The solution is: Cast cell from "id" to a specific type, preferably the correct one. Or don't use different return types for methods named "height".

Comment: I would suggest, that CGFloat is the culprit. On 32 bit CGFloat is float. On 64 bit CGFloat is double. So methods -(float)height; and -(CGFloat)height; are the same on 32 bit and different on 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. The problem was with float and CGFloat. Changed all methods to return CGFloat and that solved the problem.